# C# multiple combobox with the same itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have two comboboxes and the itemssourse for both is the same.

```
List<string> cars = new List<string>();
cars.Add("Audi");
cars.Add("BMW");
cars.Add("Mercedes-Benz");

this.ComboBox1.ItemsSource = cars;
this.ComboBox2.ItemsSource = cars;
```

Let's say that I have selected "Audi" in `ComboBox1`. What I want is when "Audi" is selected in `ComboBox1` remove/disable "Audi" in `ComboBox2`.

Could some one help me with that? (I'm new to c#/wpf programing)

Comment: You should have a look at the MVVM pattern and `ICollectionView`. It's easy to achive but hard to explain when you don't know at least MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define 2 list in public like

```
List<string> cars = new List<string>();
List<string> cars2 = new List<string>();

public CarsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cars.Add("Audi");
        cars.Add("BMW");
        cars.Add("Mercedes-Benz");

        this.ComboBox1.ItemsSource = cars;
        this.ComboBox2.ItemsSource = cars;
    }
```

and your function must be like this

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
            string cb1 = ComboBox1.SelectedValue as string;
            cars2.Clear();
            cars2.AddRange(cars);
            cars2.Remove(cb1);
            ComboBox2.ItemsSource = null;
            ComboBox2.ItemsSource = cars2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop throught second combobox items and check if selected item from first combobox exist in second combobox, if yes, then remove it, example :

```
private void comboBox1Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < comboBox2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((ComboBoxItem)comboBox2.Items[i] == comboBox1.SelectedItem)
        {
           comboBox2.Items.Remove((ComboBoxItem)comboBox2.Items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to disable item without removing it from a list you could do it because `ListItems` in your dropdownlist have an `Enabled` property. You can set this to `false` to disable them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm getting this error : Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'.

Comment: When he changes the first combobox a second time, the second combobox will not contain the previous items anymore. I would suggest a master list and update the data source of the comboboxes with a linq expression.

Comment: @TestMan are you sure you casted item to a combobox item like I did in my post? `(ComboBoxItem)comboBox2.Items[i]`

Comment: @SebastianSchulz then maybe it's better to keep it disabled / enabled without removing it..

Comment: @Roxy'Pro  `for (int i = 0; i < ComboBox2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ComboBox2.Items[i] == ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
                {
                    ComboBox2.Items.Remove((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox2.Items[i]);
                }
            }`

Comment: Yeah don't need to be removed, just don't allow to select same values in both comboboxes is enough for me at this time

Comment: @TestMan check for my Edit and try to use property IsEnabled where you can disable same item in another combobox

Comment: @TestMan if this answer was helpful to you please vote up and mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<string> MasterListCars = new List<string>();
    List<string> TempListCars = new List<string>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MasterListCars.Add("Audi");
        MasterListCars.Add("BMW");
        MasterListCars.Add("Mercedes");
        Cb1.ItemsSource = MasterListCars;
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TempListCars = MasterListCars.Where(x => x != Cb1.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToList();
        cb2.ItemsSource = MasterListCars;
    }
```

This way you don't need to worry about adding or deleting items. 
if you want to have combobox2 populated on launch add into MainWindow():

```
cb2.ItemsSource = MasterLineCars;
```